# MyEclipse 2017 CI errors with Preferences window

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

**Resolved:** I resolved this by just creating a new workspace. I'm not sure exactly what happened to corrupt my old workspace, hard to tell and hard to resolve.

---

I just installed MyEclipse 2017 CI and converted my old 2016 CI workspace. I did some messing around with my theme, not really sure exactly what I did, nothing out of the ordinary, restarted my Eclipse client, and now I get errors when I try to navigate to Window > Preferences.

Specifically, when I first click Preferences, I get this error, and the Preferences window doesn't open:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-04-25 15:56:19.105
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollBarsProvider not initialized
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite.createScrollBar(ScrolledComposite.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite.<init>(ScrolledComposite.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageContainer(PreferenceDialog.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createDialogArea(PreferenceDialog.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.access$5(PreferenceDialog.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.lambda$0(PreferenceDialog.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createContents(PreferenceDialog.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.createDialogOn(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(PreferencesUtil.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(PreferencesUtil.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

If I click Preferences a second time, it will open, but none of the preference screens display. When I click a tab to get a screen to display, I get a popup that states "The currently displayed page contains invalid values", along with the following error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2017-04-25 16:02:11.702
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4514)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkParent(Widget.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.<init>(Widget.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.<init>(Scrollable.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.<init>(Composite.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1430)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.lambda$0(PreferenceDialog.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:878)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.lambda$1(OpenStrategy.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4203)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3819)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is going on there, looks like the window model got messed up. In the interests of getting back to work, I suggest either opening a New Window (Window->New Window0 then closing the old window. If that doesn't work, try opening MyEclipse on a new, empty, workspace and import your projects from the old workspace. You may have to reset some preferences and define servers again but at least you'd be up and running! If you make some theme changes again, make a note of what you did as that seems like the source of the problem.

Comment: I did try a fresh workspace and everything works fine. Also tried comparing workspace settings files with my fresh one and my broken one, but there are too many differences to sift through.

I did actually fix my Preferences issue. I did this by opening the workspace up in ME CI 2016, changing the theme back to default there. Then when I opened the workspace in CI 2017, the Preferences window worked fine, but I then had issues with the Servers tab.

I think my best bet is probably to just make a new workspace and start fresh, but I was trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: I wish I could remember exactly what I did to get myself in this situation in the first place but I can't!